# _.groupBy momentjs format returns key undefined

Tags: javascript, group-by, lodash

[image]

I'm trying to group these records by date like: `2018/02/28`.

My code is using lodash's _.groupBy function.

```
let groupedData = _.groupBy(data, access_log => {
    moment
      .utc(access_log.last_access_at)
      .local()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  });
```

This returns the grouped data fine, but the key for the group is `undefined`. Shouldn't it be returning the date as `"2018/02/28` given the format matcher?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything. Just Add a `return` before `moment.utc(access_log.last_access_at) .local() .format("YYYY-MM-DD");`  Since you added **{}** inside fat arrow function you need to **specify return** keyword else remove **{}**

```
let groupedData = _.groupBy(data, access_log => { return moment .utc(access_log.last_access_at) .local() .format("YYYY-MM-DD"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your code missing return statement, please try

```
let groupedData = _.groupBy(data, access_log => (moment
      .utc(access_log.last_access_at)
      .local()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  ));
```

or

```
let groupedData = _.groupBy(data, access_log => {
    return moment
      .utc(access_log.last_access_at)
      .local()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  });
```